# How do I get my google account/profile pic to show as a map marker to my current location in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I have played with google maps on android for quite some time.I just couldn't find any link/reference as to do this.

Is there any way I could retrieve my google account profile pic from any of my signed in accounts?I want to use it as a marker for my current location.Google maps application does this and its pretty neat when you are trying to show your current location.

Thanks for any help...